# WebRequest's callback doesnt get called unless calling thread is free (method is finished)

Tags: c#, silverlight, asynchronous, callback, webrequest

Here is my code (It's Silverlight!):

```
public class ThreadTester
{
    public void Test()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Outer thread start");
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x => RunInner());
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Debug.WriteLine("Outer thread end");
    }

    private void RunInner()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Inner thread start");

        BL bl = new BL();
        bl.Run1(AssyncCallback);

        Debug.WriteLine("Inner thread end");
    }

    public void AssyncCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Async Callback called!");
    }

}

public class BL
{
    public void Run1(AsyncCallback callback)
    {
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(@"http://microsoft.com");
        req.BeginGetResponse(callback, null);
    }
}
```

This is what I get in output window:

```
Outer thread start
Inner thread start
Outer thread end
Inner thread end
Async Callback called!
```

Any ideas why it works that way? Shouldnt it be

```
Outer thread start
Inner thread start
Async Callback called!
Inner thread end
Outer thread end
```

Main emphasis is on Callback call.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The point of the callback is that it is something to invoke only after your request is complete and your response is received.

This appears to be taking more than 2 seconds, so the thread end messages happen before the callback.

Further, the `Outer thread end` gets written as soon as the 2 seconds is up, whereas everything *within* `RunInner()` happens synchronously, so `Inner thread end` doesn't show up until after the request is complete (but before the callback executes, because you are using the asynchronous `BeginGetResponse`).

When I run your same code, I actually get this output:

> ```
> Outer thread start
> Inner thread start
> Inner thread end
> Async Callback called!
> Outer thread end
> ```

This just means that the request took less than 2 seconds for me. If you increase your `Thread.Sleep()` value by a few seconds, you should get the same result. Again, though, the callback is being invoked asynchronously, so the `Inner thread end` message will typically precede it, but with asynchronous processing you should not rely on that.

Let me know in the comments if this is not clear, and I will try to illustrate further.

#### edit

Now that I see that you are using Silverlight, the issues are becoming clearer. I think that if you take this through to actually calling `EndGetResponse()`, you'll end up with a `SecurityException`, because Silverlight wants to block cross-site scripting attacks, by default. That is, you can't access URLs in domains different than the one in which your Silverlight application lives (like microsoft.com or google.com) without establishing a policy that allows it.

There is a detailed treatment of security policies here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032(v=VS.95).aspx

Comment: Ok, I changed wait time to 10 seconds, same output. So your idea about it taking a bit more then 2 secs doesnt work.

Comment: @deafsheep How many seconds does it take microsoft.com to open in your browser? Why don't you try a lighter site, like google.com?

Comment: maybe 1-2 secs (with all images, redirects etc). It's not that, I am telling you, tried google.com - all the same. Seems like something is blocking request. Any ideas?

Comment: I am very sorry Jay, it all happens inside silverlight (forgot to mention it), on button click event (ThreadTester.Test() gets called)

Comment: @deafsheep Okay, I am calling this from a console application. I'll try to investigate further tonight (UTC -5:00); sorry I can't get to it sooner.

Comment: Ok that google.com was kinda stupid of me, so I changed it to "http://localhost:64198/data.htm" which is local url for site and it gets downloaded successfully, BUT still same order: Outer thread start
Inner thread start
Outer thread end
Inner thread end
Async Callback called! And it's with 10 sec delay. Any ideas now?:) (btw your help is really appreciated)

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        private WebRequest m_request;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MessageBox.Show("began!");
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => Run1(AssyncCallback));

        }

        public void Run1(AsyncCallback callback)
        {
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show("run called"));
            m_request = WebRequest.Create(@"http://localhost:9892/testGet.htm");
            m_request.BeginGetResponse(callback, null);
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show("finish"));
        }

        public void AssyncCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show("inside"));
            try {
                m_request.EndGetResponse(ar);
                Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show("ok"));

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show(e.Message));
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Works fine with my local machine where testGet.htm is local to SL application.
Message boxes are shown began ,run called, inside, ok and then 5 secs later finished

**Edit:**

What you are suggesting in theory cant possibly work, if we have following code change like u suggest:

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MessageBox.Show("began!");
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => Run1(AssyncCallback));
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            MessageBox.Show("outer ended")
        }

        public void Run1(AsyncCallback callback)
        {
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show("run called"));
            m_request = WebRequest.Create(@"http://localhost:9892/testGet.htm");
            m_request.BeginGetResponse(callback, null);
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show("finish"));
        }
```

You cannot expect any message box to be shown before "outer ended" is shown because its equivalent to calling

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("one");
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    MessageBox.Show("one ended");
                });
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => MessageBox.Show("two"));
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => MessageBox.Show("three"));
```

if ThreadPool MaxThreads was 1. You cannot expect that "two" will be shown before "one ended" , it cannot inject in the middle of execution of first queued delegate.

Comment: while that solution does work it doesnt capture the idea of original problem - wait for async call end in original, UI thread. If you remove wait from Run1, and place it in MainPage() after ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => Run1(AssyncCallback)); and put message box like MessageBox.Show("outer ended!"); after the sleep, in theory you should see "outer ended!" message box last, but it never happens like that, it always shows first.

Comment: That "theory" doesn't go along with the way UI thread works. method running in UI thread has to return before other methods can call MessageBox.Show on UI, before its not complete all they do is put their calls in queue to execute on UI thread, much like ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem would work if threadpool had 1 thread in it.

Comment: Yes, you are right, that "outer ended" will be delayed bc of we put UI thread to sleep for 5 secs, but that does not solve the problem: Callback does not get called before UI method is finished (i. e. UI thread is free). the order of message boxes shows that (callback is always last)